# Binding Image Source url with Json Key

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, data-binding

Here is my `XAML Code`

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Categories" Margin="12,0,12,8">
    <ListBox x:Name="ImageList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="420">
                    <StackPanel Height="325" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image x:Name="eventImage" Source="{Binding category_image}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Here I am binding the image with a variable which I have taken in my class `Category` which look like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public string post_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string category_image { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the value of `category_image` like this:

```
 JArray categories = (JArray)post["posts"];
```

The value of `categories` as below

```
[
    {
        "post_id": "5",
        "category": "Hospitals",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/hospitals.png"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "2",
        "category": "Play Schools",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/playschool.png"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "4",
        "category": "Fitness",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/gym.png"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "7",
        "category": " Salon & Spa",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/BEAUTY.png"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "12",
        "category": "Food & Drink",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/restaurants.png"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "13",
        "category": "Car Care",
        "category_image": "http://right.mydomain.com/deal_img/carwash.png"
    }
]
```

Now I am stuck here what next I have to do, to show the image dynamically with the help of `URL` binding.

Comment: consider implementing some kind of lazy loading, otherwise you may get an out of memory exception

Comment: can you please provide the link to learn the same, as I am beginner in windows phone development.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in code as below :

In `XAML` file below

```
<ListBox x:Name="ImageList" DataContext="{Binding}">
```

In code side add below code

```
JArray categories = (JArray)post["posts"];
DataContext = categories
```

**Edit:**

Put in XAML:

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="pivotItem">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Categories" DataContext="{Binding}" FontSize="10">
        <ListBox x:Name="ImageList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=posts}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Height="323" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Path=category_image}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="323" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Put in .cs file:

```
RootObject Item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JStr);
DataContext = Item;
```

**Last Edit:**

Put in XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoots" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivotItem" Title="Test Category">          
            <!--Pivot item one -->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Categories" DataContext="{Binding}" FontSize="10">
                <Grid>
                    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsCategoriesList" Grid.Row="0"
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            LayoutMode="List"
                                            IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                                            HideEmptyGroups="true"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=posts}">
                        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Grid Width="Auto">
                                        <StackPanel Height="323" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Path=category_image}" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="323" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: No luck found by this, can you please send me the links of good tutorial ( documented or video) from where I can learn the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while using you updated code I am receiving an exception, Exception : A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
 The same exception is there which I use LongListSelector Instead of ListBox.

Comment: I update XAML file code and update my answer check it